Nessus scanner /bin/sh -c 'printf "command_start_%s" "RandomALPHANUM"; netstat -a -n; printf "command_done_%s" "RandomALPHANUM"'
This is a Nessus scanner command
I wan't to know what the Random Alphanum means, is it an encoded timestamp? or is it just a random alphanumeric for some Nessus function?
/bin/sh -c 'printf "command_start_%s" "randomalphanum"; netstat -a -n; printf "command_done_%s" "randomalphanum"'
i did not find information
